# How to create ipad PopUpOver?

Tags: ios, ipad, ios6, popup, uitoolbar

I need to create a `PopUpOver` for the `iPad` .I need to create PopUpOver just like below images.

Actually I am confuse what will be called this PopUpOver and what are the class available to draw these types of PopUpOver for the ipad.

please let me know what it is and how it will be created?
image 1) options PopUpOver(black image)
image 2)  that sharing option popup

[image]

[image]

Comment: firstly I am searching what it is..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply design your own view and add it on selected view/ rect

```
    popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imagePickerController];
    popoverController.delegate = self;
    [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:self.view.bounds inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

and dont forgot to include < UIPopoverControllerDelegate > delegate in .h file

Comment: and how to give the different buttons into that??

Comment: Its your own customized view, normally how you will provide button action just simply provide same as it.

Comment: and what it is imagePickerController

Comment: @Christien Thats the contentViewController of UIPopoverController which is going to use. Just check it any sample project of UIPopOver Controller, you will get clear idea.

Answer (score 1):

For option 1 you need `UIPopoverController`, you have the docs and code examples [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009306)

For option 2 you need `UIActivityViewController`, doc [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: I actually wanted the `UIActivityViewController`  for sharing purpose but problem is that UIActivityViewController support only `ios6` not before that..what can I do to support before ios version for sharing purpose..

Comment: For previous versions you have to use the UIActionSheet, but it doesn't have icons, just buttons.

Comment: ok thanks man!! and one more doubt plz clear ..in image 1, which is UIPopoverController the icons are on which thing?? means it is not on the UIActionSheet..

Comment: In the UIPopoverController you can load a custom UIViewController. If you create the .xib file with the buttons you want. BTW, the UIPopoverController only works on iPad, the UIPopoverController in image 1 isn't a real UIPopoverController, it's just a UIView with buttons that they show when you tap the Options button.